# How to Update asp:label from the response HttpWebResponse in asp.net Page_Load?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, httpwebresponse

I'm new to vb.net and asp.net. I'm trying to update an asp: label in Page_Load. The value of the label is coming from a Webservice all.

vb.net code :

```vb
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then lblMaxValue.Text = " Value is: " & GetRequestResponse(URL)
```

service code:

```vb
Private Sub GetRequestResponse(uri As Uri, callback As Action(Of String))
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(uri), HttpWebRequest)

    request.Method = "GET"
    request.ContentType = "application/json"

    request.BeginGetResponse(
        Function(x)
            Using response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.EndGetResponse(x), HttpWebResponse)
                If callback IsNot Nothing Then

                    Dim reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
                    Dim streamText As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
                    callback(streamText)
                End If
            End Using
            Return 1
        End Function, Nothing)
End Sub
```

No Error but value is not updating.

Comment: GetRequestResponse is a Sub so it doesn't return a value. It would need to be a Function in order to return anything to put in the label. Please ensure you understand the difference between Sub and Function in vb.net

Comment: Thank you @ADyson. But there is a callback. I converted Sub to Function but still, it's not working.

Comment: `lblMaxValue.Text =...` should be somewhere in `callback`.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev I can see the value but the value is not updating in the label. Is it something like the main thread or Async? I am trying to call JS function also System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(Page), "Script", "updateMaxPickUp();", True) This is also not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options:

1. Make it synchronous; or
2. Use a ScriptManager, Update panels, Timer and session variable; or
3. Use AddOnPreRenderCompleteAsync as below (and further [described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx#S2)):

aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" Async="true" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.vb" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="lblMaxValue" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO

Partial Class Default2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private _request As HttpWebRequest

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            Dim uri As New Uri("http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json")
            _request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri)
            AddOnPreRenderCompleteAsync(New BeginEventHandler(AddressOf GetRequestResponse), New EndEventHandler(AddressOf EndAsyncOperation))
        End If
    End Sub
    Protected Function GetRequestResponse(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs, ByVal cb As AsyncCallback, ByVal state As Object) As IAsyncResult
        Return _request.BeginGetResponse(cb, state)
    End Function

    Private Sub EndAsyncOperation(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
        Dim text As String

        Using response As WebResponse = _request.EndGetResponse(ar)

            Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
                text = reader.ReadToEnd()
            End Using
        End Using

        lblMaxValue.Text = " Value is: " & text
    End Sub

End Class
```